# Cant finish syncronization

Tags: daemon

Good Day
I hope someone can assist me.I have downloaded monero and the syncronization has been busy for 50hours and it has downloaded 77GB excluding the 30GB LMBD folder. i need to know how much will it continue to download as i am out of space and when i want to start mining it cant start. This is in my log when  type Help and press enter:
[5/3/2020 9:06 PM] 2020-05-03 19:06:31.966 I Monero 'Carbon Chamaeleon' (v0.15.0.1-6def88ad4) 
2020-05-03 19:06:31.968 I Generating SSL certificate 
Monero 'Carbon Chamaeleon' (v0.15.0.1-6def88ad4) 
Commands: 
alt_chain_info [blockhash] 
ban [] 
banned 
bans 
bc_dyn_stats 
check_blockchain_pruning 
diff 
exit 
flush_cache bad-txs 
flush_txpool [] 
hard_fork_info 
help [] 
hide_hr 
in_peers 
is_key_image_spent 
limit [] 
limit_down [] 
limit_up [] 
mining_status 
out_peers 
output_histogram [@] [] 
pop_blocks 
print_bc [] 
print_block | 
print_cn 
print_coinbase_tx_sum [] 
print_height 
print_net_stats 
print_pl [white] [gray] [pruned] [publicrpc] [] 
print_pl_stats 
print_pool 
print_pool_sh 
print_pool_stats 
print_status 
print_tx [+hex] [+json] 
prune_blockchain 
relay_tx 
rpc_payments 
save 
set_bootstrap_daemon (auto | none | host[:port] [username] [password]) 
set_log | 
show_hr 
start_mining [|auto] [do_background_mining] [ignore_battery] 
status 
stop_daemon 
stop_mining 
sync_info 
unban 
update (check|download) 
version

Comment: Showing the output of the `help` command isn't of any use to anyone except you, it just prints the names/docs of the commands you can run. Run `status` instead.

Comment: As @jtgrassie said, please type `status` and post the output here such that we can investigate and assist with resolving your issue.